# Optimizing Large Data Intersect

Tags: perl

I have two files from which a subset looks like this:

**regions**

```
chr1    150547262       150547338       v2MCL1_29.1.122 .       GENE_ID=MCL1;Pool=2;PURPOSE=CNV
chr1    150547417       150547537       v2MCL1_29.1.283 .       GENE_ID=MCL1;Pool=1;PURPOSE=CNV
chr1    150547679       150547797       v2MCL1_29.2.32  .       GENE_ID=MCL1;Pool=2;PURPOSE=CNV
chr1    150547866       150547951       v2MCL1_29.2.574 .       GENE_ID=MCL1;Pool=1;PURPOSE=CNV
chr1    150548008       150548096       v2MCL1_29.2.229 .       GENE_ID=MCL1;Pool=2;PURPOSE=CNV
chr4    1801108 1801235 v2FGFR3_3.11.182        .       GENE_ID=FGFR3;Pool=2;PURPOSE=CNV
chr4    1801486 1801615 v2FGFR3_3.11.202        .       GENE_ID=FGFR3;Pool=1;PURPOSE=CNV
chrX    66833436        66833513        v2AR_region.70.118      .       GENE_ID=AR;Pool=1;PURPOSE=CNV
chrX    66866117        66866228        v2AR_region.103.68      .       GENE_ID=AR;Pool=2;PURPOSE=CNV
chrX    66871579        66871692        v2AR_region.108.32      .       GENE_ID=AR;Pool=1;PURPOSE=CNV
```

**Note:** field 1 goes from chr1..chrX

**query <s>(a somewhat standard VCF file)</s>**

```
1       760912  .       C       T       21408   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     1/1:623:99:21408,1673,0
1       766105  .       T       A       11865   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     1/1:618:99:11865,1025,0
1       767780  .       G       A       15278   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     1/1:512:99:15352,1274,74
1       150547747       .       G       A       9840    PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     0/1:645:99:9840,0,9051
1       204506107       .       C       T       22929   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     1/1:636:99:22929,1801,0
1       204508549       .       T       G       22125   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     1/1:638:99:22125,1757,0
2       2765262 .       A       G       22308   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     1/1:678:99:22308,1854,0
2       2765887 .       C       T       9355    PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     0/1:649:99:9355,0,9235
2       25463483        .       G       A       31041   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     1/1:936:99:31041,2422,0
2       212578379       .       TA      T       5355    PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     0/1:500:99:5355,0,3249
3       178881270       .       T       G       10012   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     0/1:632:99:10012,0,7852
3       182673196       .       C       T       31170   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     1/1:896:99:31170,2483,0
4       1801511 .       C       T       12218   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     0/1:885:99:12218,0,11568
4       55097835        .       G       C       7259    PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     0/1:512:99:7259,0,7099
4       55152040        .       C       T       15866   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     0/1:1060:99:15866,0,14953
X       152017752       .       G       A       9786    PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     0/1:735:99:9786,0,11870
X       152018832       .       T       G       12281   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     0/1:924:99:12281,0,13971
X       152019715       .       A       G       10128   PASS    .       GT:DP:GQ:PL     0/1:689:99:10128,0,9802
```

**Note:** there are several leading lines that comprise the header and start with a '#' char.

I'm trying to write a script that will use the first two fields of the query file to see if the coordinates fall between the second and third fields of the regions file.  I've coded it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dump;

my $bed = shift;
my $query_file = shift;

my %regions;
open( my $region_fh, "<", $bed ) || die "Can not open the input regions BED file: $!";
while (<$region_fh>) {
    next if /track/;
    my @line = split;
    $line[0] =~ s/chr//; # need to strip of 'chr' or won't match query file
    my ($gene, $pool, $purpose) = $line[5] =~ /GENE_ID=(\w+);(Pool=\d+);PURPOSE=(.*)$/;
    @{$regions{$line[3]}} = (@line[0..4],$gene,$pool,$purpose);
}
close $region_fh;

my ( @header, @results );
open( my $query_fh, "<", $query_file ) || die "Can not open the query file: $!";
while (<$query_fh>) {
    if ( /^#/ ) {
        push( @header, $_ );
        next;
    }
    my @fields = split;
    for my $amp ( keys %regions ) {
        if ( $fields[0] eq $regions{$amp}->[0] && $fields[1] >= $regions{$amp}->[1] && $fields[1] <= $regions{$amp}->[2] ) {
            $fields[2] = $regions{$amp}->[5]; # add gene name to VCF file
            push( @results, join( "\t", @fields ) );
        }
    }
}
close $query_fh;
```

The issue is that the query file is ~3.25 million lines long, and the regions file is about 2500 lines long.  So, running this takes a very long time (I quit after about 20 minutes of waiting).

I think my overall logic is correct (hopefully!), and I'm wondering if there is a way to optimize how the data is processed to speed up the time it takes to process. I think the problem is that I need to traverse the array within regions 2500*3.25 million times.  Can anyone offer any advice on how to revise my algorithm to process these data more efficiently?

**Edit:** Added a larger sample dataset, which should show some positives this time.

Comment: In general we are programmers and computer scientists rather than geneticists, so *"a somewhat standard VCF file"* means absolutely nothing to most of us

Comment: Should the seventh field of each `%regions` element really be, for example, `Pool=2`, or should it be just `2`?

Comment: Please would you show some sample data that produces something other than null output?

Comment: Your comment about the 'Somewhat standard VCF file' is fair.  I simply mean that the rest of the data looks just like the represented lines.  There's nothing genetics related that one should need to know.  To your second question, yes, I wanted to keep the field as 'Pool=2'.

Comment: If I understand your code, for each line in the query file you want to find the record in the region file that has a matching first column, and a second and third column that brackets the second column of the query. From that record you want to extract the `GENE_ID` value and use it to replace the dot `.` in the third column of the query file. Is that about right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  I also added some more test data that should include some positives this time. Sorry I didn't think to do that earlier!

Comment: Also, you have a lot of data in `%regions` that is irrelevant to this problem. Since you are asking for ways to speed up the matching process, is there ay need to keep all of this? In particular do you need the hash to be keyed by the fourth column of the regions file?

Comment: Good point.  No, I should probably trim that hash down to just what is needed.  Not sure about the key question.  I thought about building hash keys in order keep them unique, but thought it might be simpler to use the 4 column as that is always unique for each line.  You have me re-thinking this now...

Comment: How attached are you to perl?

Comment: Well, not totally attached.  Then again, I don't really know any other language as well, so I'd prefer to stick with a language I know.

Comment: I think Perl is pretty much the best language to use for this problem because of its superior text handling facilities. Take a look at my answer to see how I'm thinking with this

Comment: I just wanted to say it's nice to see a bioperl/genetics-type question with code that looks like modern Perl and not a relic circa 1994. Nice work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches that I can think of. The first is to change the keys of `%regions` to the chromosome names, with the values being a list of all the start, end, and gene ID values corresponding to this chromosome, sort by the start value.

With your new data the hash would look like this

```
(
  chr1 => [
            [150547262, 150547338, "MCL1"],
            [150547417, 150547537, "MCL1"],
            [150547679, 150547797, "MCL1"],
            [150547866, 150547951, "MCL1"],
            [150548008, 150548096, "MCL1"],
          ],
  chr4 => [
            [1801108, 1801235, "FGFR3"],
            [1801486, 1801615, "FGFR3"]
          ],
  chrX => [
            [66833436, 66833513, "AR"],
            [66866117, 66866228, "AR"],
            [66871579, 66871692, "AR"],
          ],
)
```

This way the chromosome name would give instant acccess to the right part of the hash instead of having to search through every entry each time, and the sorted start value allows a binary search.

The other possibility is to write the whole of the `regions` file to an SQLite temporary in-memory database. Once the data is stored and indexed, looking up a gene ID for a given chromosome and position will be pretty fast.

Comment: This is it! Just ran on the whole data set and got the time in at ~40 seconds.  Perfect!  Thank you very much for the help.